# Responsive grid list only with css

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design, grid

How can I build a responsive grid list only for simple text like that, only with css ?

here is an example: www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/4aj63pkk/

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do a responsive grid you will have to use % for the width and height. Then when you shrink the screen the width will respect the % of the screen. So with your class .thumbnail you should remove the max-width and min-width in pixels or change pixels to percentage.

```
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    width:80%;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

To create your ow css grid

grid.css

```
[class^='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.col-1of4 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-1of3 {
    width: 3.33%;
}

*, *.after, *.before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1of3">
        <p> First Row </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1of3">
        <p> Second Row </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1of3">
        <p> Third Row </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

col-1of3 is a column with width 33.33. If you want 4 columns you just do the math the screen size which is equal to 100% divided by 4 columns. If you put the grid inside a body then the it will take the body as 100%.

Here is a video in case you want to know the explanation of what each line in the grid.css and index.html file does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCNz7Blg9yM

Comment: right is updated now ;D, how can i have that only with css and remove the css part from bootstrap ?

Comment: If you want to have a full css grid without using bootstrap you have to create a css file call grid.css and inside the file you can put the following, see my edited answer @fatyfatoumata

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is responsive to the page width but only in groups of 4. I'm assuming this is what you want.

To do this insert 4 elements within a single div and set the div's display to inline-block. By default div elements are set to block and will occupy the entire page width no matter how big it is.

Comment: eh eh that's what i've made ;D thank you for your logic !!